# Preventing Windows Media Embed from autoplaying in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: video, embed, media, autostart, wmv

I'm amending embed code a Windows Media video on a page for a client. In the past the videos have auto-started and been no problem in any browser. Now however the client wishes auto-play to be disabled. Here's the code I'm using to embed a video:

```
        <object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" 
          id="player" width="320" height="300">
          <param name="url" 
            value="http://www.xxx.com/videoimg/xxx.wmv"  />
          <param name="src" 
            value="http://www.xxx.com/videoimg/xxx.wmv"  />
          <param name="showcontrols" value="true" />
          <param name="autostart" value="false" />
          <!--[if !IE]>-->
          <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" 
            data="http://www.xxx.com/videoimg/xxx.wmv" 
            width="320" height="300">
            <param name="src" 
              value="http://www.xxx.com/videoimg/xxx.wmv"  />
            <param name="autostart" value="false" />
            <param name="controller" value="true" />
          </object>
          <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

When I change the autostart parameter to "false" the video fails to load at all in Firefox or Chrome. Pressing the play button does nothing to get it going. In IE it works as it should.

Any ideas how I can stop the autostart from running without nerfing the video?

Thanks!

[edit]

I couldn't find any cross browser way to make this work and forcing the user to change their plugin wasn't 'allowed'. So I put up a fake video link (a screenshot of the player) and when the user clicked on the 'screen' to start the video it loads the correct code for the video and auto plays.

This is the code I use where #wmvWrap is the fake video screenshot and $wmvideo is a PHP var the HTML object embed code with the correct video links.

```
$("#wmvWrap a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wmvWrap').html('$wmvideo');
});
```

I wouldn't recommend this as a solution, but I couldn't find anything else and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

on Firefox, I updated to "Microsoft Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin" from "Windows Media Player Plug-in Dynamic Link Library" based on Npdsplay.dll and that fixed it. Now I have to figure out how to detect the latter so I can tell them to upgrade to the former. Could you post that solution if you know it?

Comment: See edit to question above for what I did, but it's not a solution.